# Как вернуть значение из onTouchListener в метод

Tags: java, android, enum, ontouchlistener

есть метод

```
public static DialogResult showDialog(Context context, String msg);
```

В нем есть 2 кнопки и обработчики касаний onTouchListener. При нажатии на кнопку необходимо вернуть значение DialogResult (Это enum, в нем 2 перечисления DIALOG_OK, и DIALOG_CANCEL), необходимо при нажатии первой кнопки чтобы метод вернул DIALOG_OK, а при нажатии второй DIALOG_CANCEL.

Но важно, чтобы метод не возвращал Null.

Делается это для того чтобы узнать на какую кнопку нажали (Отмена, или ОК), и из активити уже прописать код для этих кнопок.

```
/*
 * Created by k1ceargy on 30.11.18 (macOS 10.12)
 * */
public class ConfirmDialog {
        static Dialog dialog;

        public static DialogResult showDialog(final Context context, String msg) {
            dialog = new Dialog(context);

            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);

            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_dialog);
            final Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_continue);
            final Button cancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);

            text.setText(msg);
            dialogButton.setOnTouchListener(здесь обработчик и т.д);

            cancelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            cancelButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            v.getBackground().setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_yellow), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                            v.invalidate();
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                            v.invalidate();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
}
```

Comment: Нельзя ВЕРНУТЬ значение из листенера. Можно в листенере реализовать логику, которая будет вызывать необходимый метод в активити

Comment: а можно по подробнее ?

Comment: Для поподробнее надо видеть ваш код. В частности не совсем понятно, зачем вам `onTouchListener`и чем не угодил стандартный алгоритм работы с диалогами? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs?hl=ru

Comment: код прикрепил, я использую кастомный диалог, и для этого нужен onTouchListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `show` класса `Dialog` описывается так

```
public void show ()
```

Он ничего не возвращает. Более того, исполняется он асинхронно, т.е. как только выполнится инструкция `dialog.show();`, ваш метод завершит работу, ничего не вернув. Соответственно объявлять его надо так:

`public static` <s>DialogResult</s> **void** `showDialog(final Context context, String msg)`

За управление результатом, в вашем коде, ответственен `.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()` - вот в нем и надо реализовывать необходимую вам логику.

Сложно советовать что-то определенное не зная вашей конечной цели, но я бы вам посоветовал передавать листенеры для кнопок в метод `showDialog`, а не создавать их внутри него. Либо, если хотите оставить их внутри - передавать в метод объекты, с которыми они должны работать.

Если простыми словами, то диалог работает по принципу "выстрелил и забыл". Т.е. такой код

```
someLogic
dialog.show();
someOtherLogin
```

не прервется и не будет ожидать, когда в диалог завершится. Он честно выполнит `.show()` и сразу же перейдет к выполнению `someOtherLogic`. Вот этот принцип вам надо понять.

Один из вариантов работы с диалогом примерно такой (псевдо-java-код)

```
interface ActivityWithDialog{
    public void parseDialogResult(DialogResult result);
}

public class ConfirmDialog {
    public static void showDialog(final Context context, String msg, final ActivityWithDialog activity){
        ....
        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activity.parseDialogResult(DialogResult.CONFIRM)
            }
        }
      ....
```

И уже в вашей activity определять метод, обрабатывающий этот результат

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ActivityWithDialog{
 ....
    @Override
    public void parseDialogResult(DialogResult result){
        switch(result){
            case DialogResult.CONFIRM:
                doSomeConfirmStuff();
                break;
            ....
```

Comment: Данный диалог изпользуется везде где надо подтверждение, передавать в него OnTouchListener каждый раз не удобно, у кнопки есть эффект нажатия который в Switch(event.getAction) и идут кейсы... https://goo.gl/9WfTGK здесь оно описывается, но оно не работает....

Comment: @k1ceargy обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а если несколько диалогов в одной активности?

Comment: @k1ceargy А какая принципиальная разница? Важно понять, что ответственность за обработку результата должна быть вне диалога. Каким образом вы будете ее реализовывать - вопрос ваших предпочтений. Самый true-way - передавать `callback` в диалог.

Comment: В своем примере я, по факту, превратил `MyActivity` в провайдера функции обратного вызова. Никто не мешает сотворить отдельный класс (обычно делают внутренний class внутри класса activity) с нужным интерфейсом и передавать в диалог его инстанс с необходимой логикой. Каждому диалогу свой, уникальный, инстанс, либо один на всех, если логика позволяет.